# Push into Array from Json Angular 5

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, parsing

I'm receiving from an endpoint the following response

```
{
  "data": [{
    "volume": 4.889999866485596,
    "name": "Carton03",
    "weight": 5.75,
    "storage": 3
  }, {
    "volume": 2.6500000953674316,
    "name": "Carton02",
    "weight": 4.5,
    "storage": 2
  }, {
    "volume": 1.4500000476837158,
    "name": "Carton01",
    "weight": 5,
    "storage": 1
  }],
  "response": "true",
  "type": "Storages"
}
```

Below I'm trying to create an array at my component:

```
export class StorageComponent {
   private data: any;
   private stors: Storage [];

   constructor (private storageService: StorageService  ) {}

   storage () {
     this.data =  this.storageService.Storage(); 
     //storageService.Storage is an assistant service that parse the response 
     // and brings me back only the data-array of the response
     for (let i = 0; i < this.data.data.length; i++) {
      const storages = this.data.data[i];
      console.log(storages.storage);
      console.log(storages.name);
      console.log(storages.weight);
      console.log(storages.volume);
      this.stors[i] = storages;
     }   
  }
}
```

I have a const storages to examine that i can evaluate data
and everything is ok.

The problem is that I want to fill up my variable `stors` that is an array of Storage model which has these attributes , storage,name etc.

I'm trying to do that through the last line but something is wrong ,
getting :

```
Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying that during the first iteration of the loop, the assignment to `this.stors[0]` is not possible because it is undefined. The `stors` property has not been initialized. Consider:

```
constructor (private storageService: StorageService) {
    this.stors = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do an initialization when defining the `stors` property like this:

```
private stors: Storage[] = [];
```

you can initialize other properties as well:

```
private data: any = null;
```

you may initialize this in the constructor or ngOnInit, but I think it's a better way like this to initialize arrays directly in the properties.

Initializing your class properties will avoid this type of behavior.